# How to set up web.xml and dispatcher-servlet.xml for mapping?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want to change from @WebServlet Mapping to SpringMVC Mapping. To get comfortable with things I set up an easy simple LoginApplication with use of @WebServlet.

Now I wanted to do the switch to springMVC by adding web.xml and dispatcher-servlet.xml

I have added all necessary dependencies to my build path, including commons-logging, jstl, servlet-api, spring-aop, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-core, spring-expression, spring-web and spring-webmvc. I added @Controller @RequestMapping("XXXXX") annotations to my controllers and @GetMapping to the methods performing redirects and stuff.

Part of my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>sobster</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/sobster-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>sobster</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Part of my sobster-servlet.xml:

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sobster" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Where com.sobster is my package containing the controllers

Part of a controller:

```
    @RequestMapping("/")
    @Controller
    public class StartPageController extends HttpServlet {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      @GetMapping
      protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
          throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
      }

    }
```

I expected any request now to get handled by web.xml which looks up sobster-servlet.xml to get the controllers. sobster-servlet.xml now checks controllers in com.sobster and performs according action (redirecting to login.jsp after receiving call from "/" for example).

But all I get is HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

I appreciate any suggestions :-)

Comment: Did U started with working example ??? Does mapping work at first ???

Comment: Hi! I started with a working application i created using @WebServlet. I added web.xml and sobster-servlet.xml after adding libs to build path. The mapping did never work using spingMVC

Comment: `StartPageController` is extending `HttpServlet`. Is that right ?

Comment: This might help http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_page_redirection_example.htm

Comment: @MyTwoCents thanks for the hint. I just did the tutorial you mentioned with the exact names etc - this doesn't work for me either. I get "HTTP Status 404" once I access the page. I can access other projects running on the tomcat, but nothing related to springMVC

Comment: @DeepakSharma That's right, I used to Map with HttpServlet extension and WebServlet annotation

Comment: Finally I found a tutorial that is working for me: https://www.journaldev.com/14476/spring-mvc-example
Thanks for all your help, I'm gonna try to convert these instructions to the project given in this question and update you on this.

Answer (score 0):

The starPageController class should be like the below code. The response of the method login will redirect to loginPage.jsp. The complete URL is decided by the InternalResourceViewResolver class which is configured below

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public class StartPageController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String login(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response,ModelMap model) throws Exception {
       return "loginPage";
   }
}
```

The sobster-servlet.xml should look like below. The bean class InternalResourceViewResolver is for redirecting to the jsp page with prefix as /pages and the suffix .jsp will now has the redirect path to "/pages/loginPage.jsp" within the war file.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.sobster" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this did not do the trick. As i start tomcat there is the error message: "Marking servlet sobster as unavailable". Not sure if it was there last time as well. Appreciate your efford!

Comment: Did you add the sobster-servlet.xml in WEB-INF folder?

Comment: yep, i have web.xml and sobster-servlet.xml in my WEB-INF folder. My controllers are located in com.sobster package and view JSPs are located in WEB-INF/pages

Comment: Are you having prefix /WEB-INF/pages/?  and the page name is loginPage.jsp?

Comment: That's right. In the mean time I found another tutorial that is working for me. The main difference I notice is ```<init-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/sobster-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>``` in web.xml servlet, but i'm not able to convert these changes to make this project run yet

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway. I appreciate your effords!